# SQL Access VBA Excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I got this code:

```
 SQLQ = "SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE bsn = '" &
 Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QueryResult").Range("B1").Value,
 "#########000000000") & "' AND datum= '#" &
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Initiële berekening").Range("C6").Value & "#'"
     Debug.Print SQLQ
     objRs.Open SQLQ, con, adOpenStatic
```

When I run this I get an error from VBA.
"Data type mismatch in criteria expression" (Error -2147217913(80040e07))

With the debug.print I check if it gets the right values and it does so I don't get what I do wrong..

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes around the date (next to the #).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will also need to format the date expression:

```
 SQLQ = "SELECT * FROM blabla WHERE bsn = '" &
 Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QueryResult").Range("B1").Value, "#########000000000") & "' AND datum= #" &
 Format(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Initiële berekening").Range("C6").Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```